# Nix channels and GHC/Hackage package versions

Tags: haskell, nix

I'm currently working through [Gabriel's tutorial](https://github.com/Gabriel439/haskell-nix) on *Nix and Haskell*.

In nix there are [channels](https://nixos.org/channels/) and they contain
 (similar to the Stack LTS versions)
a curated set of Hackage packages and a GHC compiler.

For every
LTS version [Stackage](https://www.stackage.org/) shows the version of the GHC compiler and the version
of every Hackage package. Where can I lookup this information for the nix channels before I start using the channel ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a revision hash, let's say `683c68232e91f76386db979c461d8fbe2a018782`, you can list all packages from that revision with

```
nix-env -qaP -f https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs-channels/archive/683c68232e91f76386db979c461d8fbe2a018782.tar.gz
```

You can also mix and match packages from different revisions. The only shortcoming there is that there is no official way to search old versions of a package.

I wrote https://lazamar.co.uk/nix-versions to help with that. It shows all past versions of a package, what derivations they are from and how to install them.

Answer (score 0):

For the version of the Haskell packages I have found an answer: There are files like https://raw.githubusercontent.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/release-16.09/pkgs/development/haskell-modules/hackage-packages.nix. These files are not really easy to use ...

**Edit**

In this file I can 
search for `= "base"` then I can find the version of the `base` library. 
From the version of the base library I can [lookup](https://wiki.haskell.org/Base_package) of the GHC version.

This gives the following table:

```
newest   -> base-4.10.0.0    -> GHC 8.2.1
17.09    -> base-4.10.0.0    -> GHC 8.2.1
17.03    -> base-4.9.1.0     -> GHC 8.0.2
16.09    -> base-4-9.0.0     -> GHC 8.0.1
16.03    -> base-4.8.2.0     -> GHC 7.10.3
15.09    -> base-4.8.2.0     -> GHC 7.10.3
```

However a simpler method would be nice...

Comment: Can we just do ` (import <nixpkgs> {}).ghc ` in the repl  (or evaluate it otherwise) to get the ghc version? There's also https://nixos.org/nixos/packages.html?channel=nixos-20.03&query=ghc (I believe the search employed there is quite basic and `ghc` doesn't show up on the first page despite the exact match. But you get the idea.)